# Issues with manipulating a drop down in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently using vanilla JS to match a given string, and then populate a drop down based on the match.  I want to be able to click the drop down once to populate the drop down, but I currently have to click twice to then select the option, which would then add the same entries again (which isn't so much of an issue as once an option was selected, I can always reset the length to 0 so the user would likely not notice).  I was thinking perhaps I need two event listeners instead of one but unsure of what direction to go or perhaps a "clickdown" and "clickup" event (if they even exist for mouse clicks?).

I'm still very much a beginner and not sure if what I am wanting to achieve is possible in one click or perhaps my approach is incorrect, so any pointers would be great.

```js
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('click', function() {
    function addType(mactype) {
        var type = document.getElementById('mode');
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = mactype;
        type.add(option);
    }
    var macinput = MACinput.value;
    var macoutput = MACoutput.value;
    if (macinput.length > 0) {
        var pattern = new RegExp("....-....-....");
        if (pattern.test(macinput) == true) {
        addType("Huawei -> Colon");
        addType("Huawei -> HP");
        addType("Huawei -> String");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `change` event on the dropdown, not `click`. This will run when the user selects a different item from the menu.

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're using here too? Also, just like @Barmar, I suggest you use a different event listener. If you want the dropdown to be populated as soon as a string matching the `RegExp` is typed in, you should use the `change` listener. If you want to do it whenever the user focuses away from the textbox, use `blur`.

Comment: @tripathiakshit For a textbox, `change` isn't triggered until you navigate away. You're thinking of `edit`.

Comment: Oh I see, my apologies. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Sure, this is the dropdown (I did have options, then removed them as I realised I wanted to add all the elements to it based on the regex match - though I may add an option back in to say "click to select type" or something and then delete it/change it on the click)
```<div id="form" align="center">
    <select id="mode" name="macs">
    </select>
</div>```

Comment: I just tried the change event and that was exactly what I was looking for.  I just had to add a new event above the click option.  Thanks guys!